# Datastore API and GAE/PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to check the documentation however data access with GAghE/PHP is through the Cloud SQL API, where locally achieved through local MySQL instance.

However, I want to know how to access the Datastore API with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to access the datastore via its new API (developers.google.com/datastore) using the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.6.3.tar.gz). We plan to have a how-to post on that soon.
And, see [this post](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/08/06/using-the-google-apis-client-library-for-php-with-app-engine/) for more info on using the APIs client library.

Answer (score 0):

Two tutorials to get you started

https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/12/23/getting-started-with-the-cloud-datastore-on-php-app-engine/

https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/12/24/getting-started-with-the-cloud-datastore-on-php-app-engine-part-ii/

Not this is wrapper around the json api for datastore.  And it was lacking in support for any datatypes other than strings.  I added the code for integers, but have not put together a pull request yet.